# Show child element on hovering upon parent element

Tags: css, hover

I am trying to make .work--strategy, .work--service and .work--design visible on hovering upon their parent div's. Below is the code for it. Right now it only works if someone overs upon the child with this code.

```
.work--service_provided:hover .work--strategy,.work--service_provided:hover .work--design,.work--service_provided:hover .work--dev{
    visibility:visible !important;
}
```

I built a [fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/teo3c2rh/) but the fiddle works fine.

Comment: We need to see your html, too, so we have a [mcve]

Comment: You would need jQuery for that, as CSS has no knowledge of a parent selector.

Comment: I figured it out. I was targeting the wrong parent in my code. What should i do with the question?

Comment: Since this is merely a logic error, future users won't benefit much from it so I suggest you delete it

Answer (score 0):

Style is Fine maybe some other class over right it
us Js

there is a sample by me
https://jsfiddle.net/teo3c2rh/1/

```
$('.work--service_provided').hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass('active')
},function(){
    $(this).removeClass('active')
});
```